# I want to display POP UP Window in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, commandbutton

For example,  I have 3 command buttons in same page block table, clicked 2nd command button , its needs to display  "POP Button " , will we copy first command data to here ?

YES or NO . like that I want to display.

Comment: Are you talking about confirm dailogs? Like in here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

Comment: Do you have a piece of code to illustrate what you really want because it's not really clear !

Comment: No, I don't have the code. It's similar to dailogs only. will we do it in VF ?

Comment: Like said highfive, you can use Javascript confirm dialog.

Comment: Could you give me the link for this ? thank you

Comment: See my answer below to display a confirm dialog (that's the link highfive gave you !).

Comment: Did you manage to achieve what you wanted with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to your `apex:commandButton` definition:

```
onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) { return };"
```

This will cause your `action` only to be fired if the user select <kbd>Ok</kbd> in the popup confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript code to display a confirm dialog popup :

```
var txt;
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```